# Don't generate apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Help me please.
Can not create apk. The application works in the emulator.

Maybe you need to do something in the gradle?

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shcherbuk96.example2firebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Errors:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

Error:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class
```

I change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFpOR.png)

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti I add build.gradle in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

It means that you are adding the same class twice (with different versions).

It happens because you are using **FirebaseUI**.
**Each version of FirebaseUI has dependency on a fixed version of firebase libraries.**

Check [the table](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

For convenience, here are some examples:

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
1.2.0               10.2.0
1.1.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.0               9.8.0
0.6.2               9.8.0
0.6.1               9.6.1
0.6.0               9.6.0
```

Then you **have to change** your dependencies:

```
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
```

Also if you are upgrading a project to version 1.x.x you may encounter the error `Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.x.x` when syncing your project with Gradle.
**Version 1.0.0 has added a new required configuration step.**

To resolve this issue you must add the Fabric repository to your repositories:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

[More info here.](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/392)

Comment: I changed.
Errors:
Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0
<a href="openFile:H:/android/AndroidProjects/AndroidStudioProjects/example2firebase/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: You have to add: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}`

Comment: I added a photo to the question after the version change

Comment: I have it:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: @shcherbuk Mark the answer if it resolves your issue. It can help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is inside the `gradle` file, not manifest.

All firebase and support libraries should be of the same version. Check it and set them to the save version.

You should update your firebase dependencies:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
```

Also add the following, if you haven't done it already:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }
}
```

([more here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#configuration))

P.S: try to not use `example` in your package name

Comment: I add build.gradle in my question. 
Look here please

Comment: I added a photo to the question after the version change